# Automap reflect tables within a postgres schema with sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm following the sqlalchemy documentation for reflecting database tables using `automap`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#generating-mappings-from-an-existing-metadata.

When I don't specific a schema, and Postgres uses the default `public` schema, this works as expected, and I find the names of my tables:

```
>>> m = MetaData()
>>> b = automap_base(bind=engine, metadata=m)
>>> b.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
>>> b.classes.keys()
['ads', 'spatial_ref_sys', 'income']
```

But when I specific an explicit schema, I don't have access to the tables in `Base.classes` anymore.

```
>>> m = MetaData(schema='geography')
>>> b = automap_base(bind=engine, metadata=m)
>>> b.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
>>> b.classes.keys()
[]
```

The MetaData reflected correctly though:

```
>>> b.metadata.tables
immutabledict({geography.usa_cbsa_centroids': Table('usa_cbsa_centroids', MetaData(bind=Engine(postgresql://asteroids:***@localhost:5432/asteroids)), Column('GEOID', VARCHAR(length=5), table=<u
sa_cbsa_centroids>, nullable=False), ...})
```

Note that the tables and columns are only known at runtime.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is that database tables in SQLAlchemy require a primary key, and my table didn't have one. There is additional information on this page: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key.

> The SQLAlchemy ORM, in order to map to a particular table, needs there
>   to be at least one column denoted as a primary key column;
>   multiple-column, i.e. composite, primary keys are of course entirely
>   feasible as well. These columns do not need to be actually known to
>   the database as primary key columns, though it’s a good idea that they
>   are. It’s only necessary that the columns behave as a primary key
>   does, e.g. as a unique and not nullable identifier for a row.

Thanks to Michael Bayer for answering this on the sqlalchemy mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/8F2tPkpR4bE